# UIView in UINavigationItem doesn't respond to touches

Tags: ios, objective-c

So, I have a `UINavigationController` embedded in a `UITabCarController` at `index 1`. On this `ViewController` I add a `UISearchBar` to the `UINavigationItem`. So, everything works as expected. However, I need to navigate to a new `ViewController` which then navigates to a new *instance* of the embedded VC.

The flow looks like this:

```
VC 1 -> VC2 -> V1(new instance)
```

So, `VC1` has the `UINavigationController` embedded in it.

Now, the issue is any `UIView` added to the `UINavigationItem` does not respond touches anymore, yet it is visible. I've figured that it has to do with view heir-achy .

**What I have tried:**

- Removing and reading the UISearchBar each time `VC1`'s viewWill/Did
  disappear methods are called.
- Adding the `UISearchBar` as a subView on the `UiNavigationBar`only.
- Setting the UISearchBar using `self.parentViewController...`
- bringing the UISearchBar to the front using `UIView's
  bringSubViewsToFront` method.

These either don't solve the problem or present a few one where the `UiSearchBar` does not appear at all.

If I set the `UiSearchBar` as part of my `UITableView`'s `headerView` the problem disappears but this falls outside of my UI design requirements, so is not an option.

So far the only way I can solve the issue is changing the flow of `VCs`. So instead of VC2 going to a new instance of VC1, I instead, pop `VC2` off the stack with no animation and do the required work that is needed in VC1 (existing instance). Whilst this works fine, I think it might be odd for the user as they then wouldn't be able to swipe back to `VC2` to select a different option for VC1 to preform work on. They'd need to go to `VC2` through the original invocation of it.

This is how I add the `UISearchBar` to `UINavigationItem` :

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar;
```

Comment: did you forget user Interaction  Enable?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however it doesn't solve the issue.